# Can I use my Apple Developer ID signing certificate on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: sign

I used Windows Explorer to "Install Certificate" for my certificate on my Windows 7 build machine. But I could not sign a file:

```
> signtool sign /a exefile
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Thinking that signtool needed the p12 file but wasn't saying anything, I then used Windows Explorer in an attempt to "Install PFX" but got an error from the Certificate Import Wizard saying "The Specified file is empty.".

Do I really have to do this whole "obtain a signing certificate" process all over again for each build machine platform type (macOS, Windows, Linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the certificate so long as you correctly export the cer and p12 files from the macos host and install them correctly on the windows host. I used the macos keychain app to export the certificate two times, once to export the cer file and again to export the p12 file. The reason my first attempt failed is because the p12 I assumed was correct was not at all correct. After I exported correctly, I was able to use windows explorer to double click on the two files and install them.